# Is using /dev/hwrng for raw key material secure?

Tags: keys, random-number-generator

Is using /dev/hwrng for raw key material secure (as long as you trust the hardware)?

I tested it using the `rngtest` tool and it has good output.

Comment: It's OK if the hardware was properly designed for that purpose, if the software has no bug, if no adversary controls the OS, and if noone in charge of rubber-stamping proclaims otherwise. Things may also depends on what kind of key that is, and what "raw" is taken to mean. And a former contributor stated: "NO!  /dev/hwrng is the RAW output of a hardware entropy source.  It is not conditioned, unless the hardware already has a conditioning component". Seriously, it's impossible to tell with the information given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that a contradiction in terms?

`/dev/hwrng` could be a  block device to anything at all.  If you trust the hardware, then yes. If you don't' trust the hardware, then no. The thing is that you can't tell. Nano scale technology has to be taken on trust. See [Can any part of Intel's (RdRand) random number generator be visually inspected?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/311438/56469)

> rngtest

Irrelevant. The [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) is a pseudo random number generator. And it will ace most randomness tests. Yet it's deterministic depending on the seed, and can be inverted by only looking at 624 outputs. You could simply reseed it with every restart and it will look really random. Like seeding with the time. Yet it will offer no cryptographic security. Prove that your hardware if not just:-

$$ \text{E}_{k  \oplus  id} (x) $$

where k = some shadowy agency’s key, id = a device identification/serial number and x is some counter and/or time. Perhaps using AES, or some other CSPRNG? Some form of NIST 800-90A HMAC_DRBG? It can’t be mathematically disproved by any analysis of the output data.

How can you confirm that what your generator is giving you is truly random? You can't. Last year's US [intelligence budget](https://fas.org/irp/budget/) was $60 billion. What did they spend it on?

---

Trumpet sounds! Build your own. It's relatively [easy](http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/zener/breadboard/) and the only way to have 100% certainty.

Comment: Building your own is a great way to be using poor randomness and not even know it.